# Can I make tabs in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, browser, tabcontrol

I am trying to make a web browser in Xcode 3.2 and I was wondering if I could add tab capabilities to it. I am not talking about Xcode tabs in which I can show different files, but tabs for the web browser that I am making such as the ones in Safari and Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for `NSTabView`.

Comment: Thank you! I could use that, but I was wondering if it was possible to create Safari-like tabs. Not that I don't appreciate your answer though.  Thank you again!

Comment: If you want to draw your own style of tabs, then you'll probably want to subclass NSTabViewItem and override -drawLabel:inRect: